# @ERROR: chdir failed but directory exists

Tags: rsync, busybox

I have a D-Link DNS-320 and I've [installed FFP](http://nas-tweaks.net/371/hdd-installation-of-the-fun_plug-0-7-on-nas-devices/) and I'm trying to get `rsync` running on it.

So far I've got the daemon up and running and I've defined a module in my `rsyncd.conf` like so:

```
max connections = 10
secrets file = /ffp/etc/rsyncd.secret

use chroot = false
read only = no
list = true
strict modes = false
#hosts deny = *
timeout = 600
dont compress = *.gz *.tgz *.zip *.z *.rpm *.deb *.iso *.bz2 *.tbz *.mkv *.avi *.mpg *.jpg *.rar
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
reverse lookup = no

[root]
hosts allow = *
read only = false
gid = allaccount
uid = nobody
auth users = greg
path = /mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync
comment = Fish
list = yes
```

`/mnt/HD/HD_a2` is the internal disk and `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync` exists:

```
root@nas:/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync# pwd  
/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync
```

with the following permissions:

```
root@nas:/mnt/HD/HD_a2# ls -la
total 154589
drwxrwxrwx 23 root   root            4096 Oct  2 19:44 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root            1024 Oct  2 17:20 ..
drwxrwxrwx  4 root   root            4096 Dec 29  2013 Ajaxpf
drwxrwxrwx 21 nobody allaccount      4096 Oct  2 15:45 NAS
dr-xr-xr-x  4 root   root            4096 Sep 24 17:45 Public
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root            4096 Sep 24 17:45 Users
drwxr-xr-x 17 root   root            4096 Aug 27 14:11 ffp
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root            1117 Oct  2 17:20 ffp.log
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root            1942 Sep 23 17:29 fun_plug
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root            4096 Jul 15  2012 logs
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody allaccount      4096 Oct  2 21:09 rsync
```

I have the user `greg` defined in my `rsync.secret` file and I can successfully connect from my (Windows) client and list the module:

```
C:\Batch\rsync> rsync greg@nas::  
root            Fish
```

**However;** When I try to send a file I get `@ERROR: chdir failed`:

```
C:\Batch\rsync> rsync -vvvv SRC test.txt greg@nas::root/test.txt  
opening tcp connection to nas port 873  
Connected to nas (192.168.10.5)  
note: iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8") succeeded.  
sending daemon args: --server -vvvve.Lsf . root/test.txt  
@ERROR: chdir failed  
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=5, file=/usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/main.c, line=1516): entered  
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/main.c  
(1516) [sender=3.0.9]  
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=5, file=/usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/main.c, line=1516): about to call
 exit(5)
```

I'm using Cygwin `rsync` version 3.0.9 on the client and `rsync` version 3.1.0 on the server.

On the server, `rsync` is running as root:

```
root@nas:/mnt/HD/HD_a2# ps aux | grep rsync  
root     10074  0.0  0.3   1996   376 ?        Ss   21:57   0:00 /ffp/bin/rsync --daemon --config=/ffp/etc/rsyncd.conf --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log --ipv4 -vvvv
```

**Why is `chdir` failing?**

`root` can write to `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync`:

```
root@nas:/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync# touch /mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync/touch  
root@nas:/mnt/HD/HD_a2/rsync# ls -la  
total 8  
drwxrwxrwx  2 nobody allaccount 4096 Oct  2 22:21 .  
drwxrwxrwx 23 root   root       4096 Oct  2 19:44 ..    
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root          0 Oct  2 22:21 touch
```

and `rsync` is running as `root`.

There's nothing useful in the log on the server:

```
2014/10/02 22:19:35 [10391] rsyncd version 3.1.0 starting, listening on port 873  
2014/10/02 22:19:41 [10394] connect from UNDETERMINED (192.168.10.37)
```

So why is `chdir` failing? or how can I diagnose the problem further?

#### UPDATE #1

Regarding this being a duplicate of [Configuring anonymous rsync daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120679/configuring-anonymous-rsync-daemon) but the solutions pertained to SELinux being the issue. The DNS-320 runs an embedded, slimmed down version of Linux, which does not include SELinux's `getenforce` and `setenforce` commands, so if it is this, as [suggested in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120680/1731), how can I rectify it?

As these tools aren't available, what else could it be?

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved it by disabeling SELinux (CentOS 7.2) -- yes, it's an old question but first hit on google for this error message.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran in to this very issue on a QNAP device with this error;

```
ERROR: chdir failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(2547) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

I solved it in a strange way by editing the rsync.conf file to

```
use chroot = true
```

Once the initial sync finished I set it back to

```
use chroot = false
```

And now it works.

Comment: I'll never know as I got rid of the 320 a while ago. Hopefully this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an SELinux issue, it needs to know that the folder can be used by the rsync daemon. Let's consider an example, to rsync the following folder: `/home/myuser/ftp`

The following commands need to be run to set the correct SELinux context:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t rsync_data_t '/home/myuser(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv '/home/myuser'
setsebool -P rsync_client on
```

Strangely enough, I noticed the parent folder must be labelled, hence why the labelling is done on `/home/myuser` instead of `/home/myuser/ftp`. Restricting to the `ftp` subfolder is simply done in the rsync daemon configuration.

You can check the SELinux labelling by running:

```
ls -Z /home/myuser
```

An interesting article about why combining chroot and SELinux is a good idea: http://blog.siphos.be/2012/04/why-both-chroot-and-selinux/